# How do you include SSZipArchive for IOS 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, zip, ssziparchive

For the project I'm working on I needed to unzip certain files. For this, I found the library [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive). I included this in Xcode 4.2 (Right-click on the Classes folder->Add files to project, with in the dialogue the "Copy items into destination group's folder"-checkbox checked). I include the libz library (I've tried both libz and zlib1.2.5). I try to compile and suddenly I've got 20 errors:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:311:1: error: expected identifier or '(' [1]
 @class NSString, Protocol;
 ^    
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:313:19: error: unknown type name 'NSString' [1]
 FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *NSStringFromSelector(SEL aSelector);
                   ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:314:44: error: unknown type name 'NSString' [1]
 FOUNDATION_EXPORT SEL NSSelectorFromString(NSString *aSelectorName);
                                            ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:316:19: error: unknown type name 'NSString' [1]
 FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *NSStringFromClass(Class aClass);
                   ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:317:43: error: unknown type name 'NSString' [1]
 FOUNDATION_EXPORT Class NSClassFromString(NSString *aClassName);
                                           ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:319:19: error: unknown type name 'NSString' [1]
 FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *NSStringFromProtocol(Protocol *proto) NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
                   ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:319:50: error: unknown type name 'Protocol' [1]
 FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *NSStringFromProtocol(Protocol *proto) NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
                                                  ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:320:19: error: unknown type name 'Protocol' [1]
 FOUNDATION_EXPORT Protocol *NSProtocolFromString(NSString *namestr) NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
                   ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:320:50: error: unknown type name 'NSString' [1]
 FOUNDATION_EXPORT Protocol *NSProtocolFromString(NSString *namestr) NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
                                                  ^
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:324:30: error: unknown type name 'NSString' [1]
 FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
                              ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:324:53:{324:53-324:76}: error: format argument not an NSString [3]
 FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:85:49: note: instantiated from:
         #define NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(F,A) __attribute__((format(__NSString__, F, A)))
                                                        ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:325:31: error: unknown type name 'NSString' [1]
 FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLogv(NSString *format, va_list args) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,0);
                               ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:325:63:{325:63-325:86}: error: format argument not an NSString [3]
 FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLogv(NSString *format, va_list args) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,0);
                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:85:49: note: instantiated from:
         #define NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(F,A) __attribute__((format(__NSString__, F, A)))
```

These are all errors in the core library, so probably something went wrong with including the library in Xcode. I managed to narrow down the culprit to the minizip library that SSZipArchive uses (if I remove that library, the errors disappear and the compiler runs like it should), but I'm pretty stumped on why this causes the compiler to have so many issues.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After a lot of headaches, I figured out what was the problem. It turned out to be _Prefix.pch. I totally looked over it, but it turns out that I had the following line there:

```
#import "someclass.h"
```

This class was being loaded in with the .c-files of the minizip library, resulting in Objective-C headers being included in .c-files, which was something that XCode did not like. Wrapping these statements in an #ifdef statement fixed the problem:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
   #import "someclass.h"
#endif
```

Comment: I had the same problem (and error messages) after upgrading to Xcode 4.3.1 and iOS 5.1. The project used to work just fine before... the new compiler is more strict now?

Comment: Absolutely life saver! The errors presented by XCode are plain BS, thanks god for StackOverflow :)

Answer (score -1):

Refer to below link thats works with both iphone as well mac applications. [Archive and Unarchive from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762252/archive-and-unarchive-from-app/15762406#)

Comment: OP was not asking for alternatives to their method.