# Archive and Unarchive from app

Tags: xcode, zip

What is the optimised way to archive and unarchive files from iPhone application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZipArchive is the Objective-C class to compress or uncompress zip files.

It can be used for iPhone application development, and cocoa on Mac OSX as well.

look here : `http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/list`

You can download files and import them into your project to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can download ziparchive files from  http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/list and add files into your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can used below methods to archive files in a single zip file.

-(BOOL) CreateZipFile2:(NSString*) zipFile;

-(BOOL) CreateZipFile2:(NSString*) zipFile Password:(NSString*) password;

-(BOOL) addFileToZip:(NSString*) file newname:(NSString*) newname;

-(BOOL) CloseZipFile2;// close archiver instance.

You can used below methods to to unzip zip file.

-(BOOL) UnzipOpenFile:(NSString*) zipFile;

-(BOOL) UnzipOpenFile:(NSString*) zipFile Password:(NSString*) password;

-(BOOL) UnzipFileTo:(NSString*) path overWrite:(BOOL) overwrite;

-(BOOL) UnzipCloseFile;// close archiver instance.