# Lot of errors in Xcode every time I'm trying to add ZipArchive or ssziparchive

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, zlib, ssziparchive

I have a project in which I need to add the ZipArchive files and unzip a file I download but every time I try to do that i get this errors after i set everything(adding zlib in the linker and everything needed for the files to work). I add all the imports needed and I just drag the ZipArchive in the folder structure that is needed into my project.
Any help on getting rid of these errors? i've been trying for a few days and cant find the problem.
I have Xcode 4.6.3 and this is the final error i'm getting:

> Apple LLVM Compiler 4.2 Error Too many errors emitted ,stopping now

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the code you added Objective-C or C?

Comment: @Wain both, in ZipArchive there are obj-c files and in the miniZip folder inside zipArchive there are c files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you include SSZipArchive for IOS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005097/how-do-you-include-ssziparchive-for-ios-5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're including Objective-C headers when compiling C code. This is probably as a result of your .pch file. Remove Objective-C imports from the .pch file or ensure that they are wrapped in an `ifdef` to prevent them from being processed during C compilation (`#ifdef __OBJC__`).

Comment: I literally spent days trying to solve this and i didnt know ALL of my obj-c imports should be warpped so i moved all of them and i really love you for this answer.