# Error adding SSZipArchive to a project in Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compilation, ssziparchive

I'm getting many errors trying to add it.
Now is telling me this when compiling:

```
"Semantic issue: conflicting types for 'time' in crypt.h"
Implicit declaration of function 'time' in C99
```

Images (I can't post them):

https://imgur.com/ym6qwVv

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSd8G.jpg

It's the first time I've tried to add SSZipArchive to a project, and just today I've updated Xcode to 5.1.1. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or maybe the update of the SDK could have changed something.

I previously had another problem that I solved thanks to this:
[Getting a lot of strange errors in Xcode everytime Im trying to add ZipArchive or ssziparchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704276/getting-a-lot-of-strange-errors-in-xcode-everytime-im-trying-to-add-ziparchive-o)